# Product price and buy button misaligned depending on size of product name

Tags: html, css, shopify

I have created a simple product page, however the div that holds the product price and the product buy button is misaligned depending on how many rows the product name wraps over.

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot above, the second product in the row is slightly misaligned because the product names only wraps two lines.

```
<div class="main_box{% if section.settings.collection_overlay %} quick-view-overlay {% endif %}">
  <div class="box_1">
    <!-- Holds the code for the product image -->
  </div>
  <div class="desc">
    <!-- Holds the code for product name, price and buy button -->
    <h5><a href="{{ product.url | within: collection }}">{{ product.title | escape }}</a></h5>
    {% if section.settings.show_grid_type %}
    <p>{{ product.type }}</p>
    {% endif %}    
    <div class="price" >
      {% unless product.price_max == 0 and settings.custom_price0_text != blank %}
      {% if product.price_varies %}{{ 'products.product.price_from' | t }}{% endif %} 
      <span class="money">{{ product.price | money }}</span>
      <form method="post" action="/cart/add" style="display: inline;">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ product.variants.first.id }}"/>
        <button type="submit" value="Add to Cart" class="btn" style="float: right;" {% unless product.variants.first.available %}disabled{% endunless %}>
          <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true" style="float: left; color: {% if product.variants.first.available %}#107FA8;{% else %}#808080;{% endif %}" ></i>
        </button>
        <p style="display: inline-block;"/p>  
      </form> 
      {% if on_sale %}<span class="compare-price money" style="display: inline-block">{{ product.compare_at_price | money }}</span>{% endif %}
      {% else %}  
      <span>{{settings.custom_price0_text }}</span> 
      {% endunless %}   
    </div>
    {% if section.settings.show_product_reviews_stars %}
      <span class="shopify-product-reviews-badge min_height_22" data-id="{{ product.id }}"></span>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>  
    {% endif %}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use match height script -> https://brm.io/jquery-match-height/
Simply include jQuery and write:

```
$('.desc h5').matchHeight();
```

Or the via CSS you fix your problem with CSS Flexbox -> https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/